# setting value in string during the runtime

Tags: java

```
public class A {
    
    String food = "briyani";
    int age = 18;
    String name;
    String description;
    
    A(String name,String description){
        this.name=name;
        this.description =description;
    }

    public A() {}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.test();
        
    }

    private void test() {
        A a = new A("yogesh",B.DESCRIPTION );
        System.out.println(B.DESCRIPTION );
    }
}
```

```
public class B {
    public static String DESCRIPTION = "My name is yogesh. My fav food is ______. And my age is ______";
}

public class B {
    public static String DESCRIPTION = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>" +
            "<br>My name is yogesh. My fav food is %s. And my age is %d "+
            "</html>";
}
```

1.This is my code snippet... here in the blank space value of food and age should get updated during the runtime. Though the value is in different class how can I substitute the value there in B class?

2.in the second case it (DESCRIPTION) was an html code I want to send it as email so how can I substitute the values here in the place of %s and %d respectively?

Comment: You could prepare a template for use in `String.format()`, like `... DESC = "My name is yogesh. My fav food is %s. And my age is %d.";`.

Comment: Unrelated: You should probably not name your variable "desc" (for "description" I guess?), because many people will understand it as "descending" (for sorting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String.format` or `java.util.Formatter`

It could be done like this:

```
public class B {
    public static String DESCRIPTION = "My name is yogesh. My fav food is %s. And my age is %d";
}
```

```
String descValue = String.format(B.DESC, name, age);
System.out.println(descValue);
```